# How to convert \1 character as a string in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to form the command as bellow using python. python is not considering \1 as a string, seems it has a special meaning. what escape character should I use to make python consider \1 as string?

```
Python variable: 
cmd="oc get pod |egrep -v Evicted| grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+'"


Getting actual output: 
oc get pod |egrep -v Evicted|  grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+)\/\s+'

Expected string output: 
 
oc get pod |egrep -v Evicted |grep -Pv '\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+'

missing \1 in the last grep
```

Comment: use a raw string prefixed with r `r"my string with escaped characters"`

Comment: `\1` can be treated as char with ASCII code `1` - the same way `\110` is treated as char `H` and `\110\111` as text `HI`. You may need to use \\1. But if you send it to system/bash then sometimes it may needs \\\\1 because Python may convert every \\into \ -  so it converts \\\\1 to \\1  - and later system may also convert every \\ into \  so it convert \\1 to \1

Answer (score 4):

You can either double-escape your backslashes

```
"\\1"
```

or you can use a raw string literal

```
r"\1"
```

Note that if you do the latter, then you can't use the usual escape sequences either, so `\n` in a raw string literal is *literally* a backslash followed by the letter 'n', not a newline.

Comment: double \ is not working

Comment: Did you make sure to double-escape all of your backslashes? It's easy to get lost in regular expressions, especially when you end up nesting escape sequences like this.